# MVC Refactoring a [httpPost] handler on every page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms, refactoring

I have a simple form on every page of my site, the form pots back and is handled by the page controller.

ForController on each page..

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(Models.FindTutorFormModel formModel)
 {
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return Redirect("/thanks/");
   }
   return View();
  }
```

I don't really want to have to duplicate the code for every page controller in the site is there a easy way to refactor this?

Comment: Why did you delete the other question ? i have a working solution for you. This can be handled with partial views. Check the answer i posted on your other question

Comment: Sorry, re read it a few times and thought I was just asking the wrong thing. this question is sort of the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679251/mvc-3-posting-form-from-partial-view

Comment: I think that question well written with all details relevant. You should keep it for future readers with same scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best approach for your task, but you can use inheritance

```
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace MvcApplication2.Controllers
    {
        public class BaseController : Controller
        {
            public ActionResult Thanks()
            {
                return Content("Thanks!");
            }
        }

        public class HomeController : BaseController
        {
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
                return View();
            }
            public ActionResult About()
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        public class InfoController : BaseController
        {
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
```

So in every controller you'll have the same method.
I hope it helps!